# In ASP.NET Webforms, is there a way to check (at runtime) if a website as been pre-compiled or not?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, pre-compilation

In `ASP.NET Webforms`, is there a possiblity to check at runtime if website as been precompiled or not ? (eg : a property that return a boolean)

To deploy a `ASP.NET webforms` website, there is two possibilities : to run website by just copy paste all code, or use compiler (eg  :`aspnet_compiler.exe` ) to precompile code.

Comment: If checking modification date of dll files works ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a built-in property for that:  BuildManager.IsPrecompiledApp.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.isprecompiledapp%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for the full reference (it doesn't say much).